# AWS S3 bucket policies and rejected traffic

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

To prevent excessive traffic from websites deeplinking content hosted on my S3 bucket I created a bucket policy to reject such requests. Works as advertised.

My question is:

1. A HTTP 403 (Access Denied) responses still have a couple of hundred bytes each. Do I pay for these 403s?
2. All those 403's appear in the bucket access logs (it's really bad, a 500Kb log every 3 mins, millions of entries). Can I disable access logging on the bucket for certain HTTP response codes (like 403) only (leaving it active for valid ones)?

Note: I have [raised](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=136913) this question also on the AWS dev forum .. maybe there is more interest/feedback.

Comment: An AWS support member clarified: you indeed pay for "access denied" response traffic.